# Google cloud terminal: cannot create cluster after authentication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy a small test example app by following the official google guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart).

Below are the output messages and warnings after I try to create a cluster named `s`

```
> vg@cloudshell:~ (shopify)$ gcloud container clusters create s
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will have basic authentication disabled by default. Basic authentication can be enabled (or disabled) manually 
using the `--[no-]enable-basic-auth` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will not have a client certificate issued. You can manually enable (or disable) the issuance of the client cert
ificate using the `--[no-]issue-client-certificate` flag.
WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled usi
ng `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on 
node autorepairs.
WARNING: Starting in Kubernetes v1.10, new clusters will no longer get compute-rw and storage-ro scopes added to what is specified in --scopes (though 
the latter will remain included in the default --scopes). To use these scopes, add them explicitly to --scopes. To use the new behavior, set container/
new_scopes_behavior property (gcloud config set container/new_scopes_behavior true).
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=404, message=Not found: shopify.
```

I have followed the official trouble shooting guide by google, which asks me to re-auth into the project `shopify`, here are the messages

```
Enter verification code: `omitted on Stackoverflow`
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help
You are now logged in as [vg@gmail.com]
Your current project is [shopify].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Now, if I try to create a cluster, I still get the same error message 404 above. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work from the GKE console?

Comment: As I was unable to reproduce the similar issue that you have experiencing, I would recommend open a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that the product engineering team can take a look.